# Stripping and reusing a vrm from vroid

Tags: rigging

I made a character in VRoid.

Imported it into blender as a vrm, then stripped the character of its materials and armature and colliders etc. so I could just get the mesh as a base to make my own character.

Now I'm having trouble putting my own armature onto the character with automatic weight.

Normally I just select the mesh, select the bone and click parent with automate weights. But that doesn't work.

It parents, but there's no weight, the mesh doesn't move when the bone does.

What am I doing wrong?

How is this object any different from one I've made from scratch?

Blend file [image]

Comment: Firstly you have over 3000 duplicate vertices on that model. Go into Edit mode, select All and then M > merge by Distance. You'll briefly see the number of vertices which were merged on the bottom status bar. I'd also suggest that you use one of Blender's built-in armatures and then follow [this](https://youtu.be/snvlZcQUoXs) quick rigging tutorial to place the bones correctly rather than making your own armature from scratch. There's a more detailed tutorial [here](https://youtu.be/eCtSviaHZ6U).

Comment: When you parent, you get the error `Bone Heat Weighting: failed to find solution for one or more bones` displayed in the status bar in orange. There are lots of topics on this forum that give solutions for it.